# Javascript element ID visible but not accessible on keyup event

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to cycle through a list of custom autocomplete options using the arrow keys in JavaScript. I am attempting to do this by iterating through the options and adding a "selected" ID to the option currently selected. I've run in to a problem where, although the "selected" ID of the option currently selected is visible (if you log it out, you can see the ID), the ID is inaccessible (trying to log out element.id returns an empty string).

Here is the code:

```
SearchBox.prototype.handleOptionNavigation = function() {
  _this.inputElement.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    var options = _this.getOptions();
    if (event.key === "ArrowUp") _this.moveSelectedUp();
    if (event.key === "ArrowDown") _this.moveSelectedDown();
  });
}

SearchBox.prototype.getOptions = function() {
  return Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("result-item"));
}

SearchBox.prototype.getSelectedIndex = function() { //here is the problem
  var options = _this.getOptions();
  if (options.length === 0) return;
  console.log(options[2]); 
        //this returns <li class="result-item" id="selected">...</li>
  console.log(options[2].id);
        //this returns an empty string
  return 1;
        //this function is supposed to return the index of the element currently selected; 
        //I am returning 1 just to see a selected element on the screen.
}

SearchBox.prototype.moveSelectedDown = function() {
  var options = _this.getOptions();
  if (options.length === 0) return;
  var selectedIndex = _this.getSelectedIndex();
  if (selectedIndex === -1) {
    options[0].id = "selected"
  } else if (selectedIndex === (_this.maxResults - 1)) {
    options[0].id = "selected"
    options[options.length - 1].removeAttribute("id");
  } else {
    console.log("we are moving down");
    options[selectedIndex + 1].id = "selected";
    options[selectedIndex].removeAttribute("id");
  }
}

SearchBox.prototype.moveSelectedUp = function() {
  var options = _this.getOptions();
  if (options.length === 0) return;
  var selectedIndex = _this.getSelectedIndex();
    console.log(selectedIndex);
  if (selectedIndex === -1) {
    options[options.length - 1].id = "selected";
  } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
    options[0].removeAttribute("id");
  } else {
    options[selectedIndex - 1].id = "selected";
    options[selectedIndex].removeAttribute("id");
  }
}
```

The idea is that, with each press of the up or down arrows, a different element in the list of complete options will become highlighted. However, because I can't seem to access the id of the selected element, it gets stuck and the moveSelectedUp/moveSelectedDown functions don't work.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Thank you!

Comment: shouldnt you rather add the attribute `selected` than an id ?

Comment: did u try options.getAttribute('id')?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve in your method `SearchBox.prototype.getSelectedIndex`, but it is always returning 1, how is that supposed to help ?

I've updated your method so that it returns the real index and it seems to work fine, see the fiddle below :

https://jsfiddle.net/c2p1aayh/